# Will using web view be able to use camera and other cordova functions?

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to develop a mobile app, and was wondering if its easier to using webview and develop the app on a webserver. but I need to use camera and other cordova functions from phonegap, will this work?

what is the fallback on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap uses Javascript interfaces to invoke native methods. Thus the web content bundled with the app can invoke these Javascript functions to access the hardware features. [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents invoking Javascript functions from a different origin (such as a hosted web page). Thus it is not possible to access the hardware features from a hosted web page.

What is usually done is that the static HTML content is bundled with the app and dynamic content is fetched through AJAX calls. You can create web services from the server side and consume these in your PhoneGap app.

Comment: Login and sessions are handled the same way using web services together with client side storage. You can take a look at the following examples : [Example of server-based login with PhoneGap](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap) and [Sample Application using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/)

Comment: ok thanks, just to be clear, cordova.js is phonegap.js right?

Comment: Yes, [from version 1.5](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/03/21/changes-with-phonegap-1-5/)

Comment: Thanks much, this should get me started with a simple social app

Comment: I'm sorry for making this a discussion already, if its not allow here let me know, but Im trying to do something like instagram or path, editing photos, will cordova jquery mobile be able to handle this? I dont have much background with java and c, so I want to stay with jquery and html, not sure how far I can go but I want to try.

Comment: Technically it should be possible. But you should be doing some more research before you finalize.

Comment: so many variations over the net and so confusing already. but I am in no hurry to learn, just like to get a straight forward response. probably there is learning webinar I can join about apps.